# How to disable logger in logback.xml

Tags: java, logback

I am using logback.xml file to set logging env. Here I have 2 appenders one for console another for file. Console appender will always print the value but the file appender needs to open when required.

Following is my configuration, in which two appender STDOUT and file and both are added root.
What I want to control file appender log and want when I change the value of level from OFF to something else then only it should work.
Currently if change level OFF then stop both appender and not able to see anything on console.

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/tmp/logback.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.demo" level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </logger>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Following is the java code.

```java
package com.demo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class Main {
    static Logger loger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      loger.info(System.getenv("LOGFILE"));
      loger.info("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing called SNSMain, Main is name of class which logger referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<logger name="com.demo" level="OFF">
```

This `level = "OFF"` in the above tag overrides the log level - `info` of `"com.demo"` at `root` level to `"OFF"`

In a simpler way the moment we declare the `level="OFF"` to a particular logger, the logger level will be OFF in the whole application and no `appender` can print the logs for it.

Hence as per my understanding, the best solution would be to use commenting like below:

case1:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logback.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

In this case- the log will route to both console and file.

case2:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logback.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="info">
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="file" /> -->
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

In this case- the log will be routed to only the console and no log will be routed to the file appender.

**Solution-2:**

By taking help of `If condition support` in `logback.xml`, we can achieve it.

```
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <if condition='property("FILE_APPENDER_ENABLED").contains("true")'>
        <then>
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </then>
    </if>
</root>
```

Configure this property `FILE_APPENDER_ENABLED` from `environment variables`, then could `enable` or `disable` the `file appender`.

May be if this solution not suitable to you, but in future it might be useful to someone.

Comment: Hi Arun, I replaced condition with this line <if condition='property("LOGFILE").contains("on")'> and you can see print the value of env variable which log it fine.  Console is working fine but file appender is not working.

Comment: Please add the updated logback.xml in the question, want to see see how you are injecting environment variable into logack.xml

Comment: I did not add anything in logback.xml and thinking new line will itself pull env var and will compare it. Looks its not the case and need to add something in logback.xml. can you please add that line for me. :)

Comment: Hi , its working now, it was eclipse that was not populating env var. I had restart it.

Comment: Happy to hear it's working!